# Docker build hangs when adding user with a large value of user ID / UID

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, openshift, docker-build

When trying to build a docker image with a large value of UID, such as  `1000123456`, `docker build` repeatedly hangs on the line with `RUN useradd`.

To reproduce:

```bash
$ touch Dockerfile
$ echo FROM ubuntu:latest >> Dockerfile
$ echo RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u 1000123456 jovyan >> Dockerfile
$ docker build --tag mirekphd/test-uid .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> d2e4e1f51132
Step 2/2 : RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u 1000123456 jovyan
 ---> Running in 04707e01aefc
```

Any known solutions (to accept) or at least workarounds (to upvote)?

---

*More info*

This bug can manifest itself for example when trying to hard-code (for debug only) a UID within the range of values accepted by one of Openshift/OKD namespaces.

As a side-effect of this issue, the build takes up huge amount of disk space (any proposed workarounds should be free of this side-effect):

```
$ docker system prune -f
Deleted Containers:
04707e01aefcda9ce9840389f1d59821e1ddb7dac535d416f99447e657ec5309
c3fc96209790ee7aa0c2c10bec2459e8ec3dbcc1dc7cfdd0a3e12960a28b9437
1ed4985b3e27eaff6394fd0243713573473ab59c9a82db865e40ebb40a391892

Total reclaimed space: 648.1GB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `useradd`'s `--no-log-init` option (or shorter: `-l`):

```
useradd --no-log-init -m -s /bin/bash -N -u 1000123456 jovyan
```

The huge files created in the Docker image (`/var/log/faillog` and `/var/log/lastlog`) are [sparse files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530157). Using `--no-log-init` avoids creating these files (huge in the case you add a user with a large uid). Why are these files huge?

> `useradd` by default reserves space for all users, so when using (say), uid 10000, it reserves space for 10000 users, even if only user 10000 is used; for this, a sparse-file is created

Source: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2263#issuecomment-1205423533

References (it seems to be a known issue for a long time):

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5419
- https://forums.docker.com/t/run-adduser-seems-to-hang-with-large-uid

Comment: It certainly is a great workaround! And deals with the size explosion side-effect as well. Let's keep fingers crossed that Docker devs will *eventually* make it unnecessary and someone (perhaps after we have long retired:) will present a docker upgrade as a proper solution.

Comment: I mean, let's add the rant too. This issue in `moby/moby` (`#5419`) is the longest-running still open bug report I have ever seen! It's been known for over 8 years... I even now recall having run into it myself (without resolution then) some 4 years ago:)

Comment: After digging through the issue, I found that the "issue" comes from Go `archive/tar` library (used by Docker) and the way it handles sparse files: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28920#issuecomment-264037853, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13548#issuecomment-265623023. But the issue is also open there :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, introduce the following instructions:

```
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -y install strace
RUN strace useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u 123456 jovyan
```

You can see that `useradd` exits and docker build terminates as expected.

Now, change `UID` into `1000123456`: `useradd` terminates as the previous scenario, but docker doesn't.

I suppose may be a bug in the **Ubuntu image**.

I suggest you to try with another image...

Let me know if it will work.

Regards.